# Api telegram, отправка поста в канал php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, api, telegram

Отправляю через api почты в телеграм. Все работает. Единственное они (посты) все от имени бота в канале.
Как отправить пост в канал без автора? Или чтобы его не видел никто кроме администратора?
Еще, при отправке поста с ним идёт картинка, но телеграм показывает её в полный размер, разобрать что изображено не возможно, нужно создавать миниатюры перед отправкой? Или есть встроенный функционал телеграм для нормального отображения изображений?

Answer (score 0):

Указывается в настройках канала его администратором - опция "Подписывать сообщения"